# Error "Object.keys called on non-object" caused by empty json output

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I received an error `Object.keys called on non-object`. The offending code is;

```
numberOfEmployees = Object.keys(employee_data).length;
```

`employee_data` is a json object that gets assigned json output data from a web service. This error only happens when the json output is empty `[]`. If json output is not empty, there is no error. What is wrong with the code?

`employee_data` becomes `undefined` when the json output is empty `[]`.

Comment: How is the value assigned to  `employee_data`?

Comment: It is undefined when error happens

Comment: Well, you can't take `Object.keys()` of undefined. How did it get to be undefined? How is `employee_data` created or assigned to? If a web service returned undefined JSON, it probably means there was an error of some sort with the request, so you obviously need to detect that and do whatever error handling is required.

Comment: Why do I get a negative vote for this question when this question won a popular badge for 1000 views? What is wrong with the question? Would like to know to avoid asking bad questions on stackoverflow later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error Object.keys called on non-object can only occured when you put non object into it. See below in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

```
return function(obj) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'object' && (typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null)) {
        throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
      }
```

Did you test what is the value of employee_data when it is empty. It should work for **[ ]**.

But if you have called **JSON.stringify** on it,than it won't work, See below.

```
var emptyData = [];
if(typeof emptyData == 'object')
   console.log(Object.keys(emptyData)); // it will print the keys,if there

var emptyData = [];
var emptyJSOn = JSON.stringify(emptyData);
if(typeof emptyJSOn == 'object')
   console.log(emptyJson); //  it won't print because ,it's not an object.
```

Now i suppose you are trying to pass, the emptyJson to Object.keys() method,which is why you are receiving this error.

For more information on this you can refer MDN docs.

Comment: I guess you meant `if(typeof emptyData == 'object')` and `if(typeof emptyJSOn == 'object')`